# Z-index issue on the client site

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am working for an advertising agency and I created an HTML5 side-panel for the client. The right and left panels are working fine but the publisher site is having a z-index issue. The main content and the header/footer aren't clickable, while my panels at the right and left side are clickable.

I tried to add z-index in the main content and header and footer as well but nothing works. How exactly should I add z-index so that the panel and the content works fine.

This is the [testing page](http://www.smh.com.au/?adcall=true&adcallkw=MercedesParallaxTest&reload=true) .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not enough info. Are you sure the link is correct? And what is `Publisher Site` ?

Comment: yes the link is working fine can you see the panels? if you have adblocker then you need to turn off the blocker. Publisher site is the client site

Comment: `.header-wrap { position: relative; z-index: 1; }` will do the trick for you.

Comment: Thanks @vivekkupadhyay i see the header is fine but the main content (news section and the footer is not clickable

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a z-index issue. You are overlaying the entire page with an iframe, holding the ads (currently Mercedes), preventing the content to get clicked:

```
<div style="border: 0pt none; margin: auto; text-align: center;"
    id="google_ads_iframe_/6411/onl.adtester_1__container__">
    <div
        style="border: 0px none; padding: 0px; margin: 0px auto; top: 0px; left: 0px; overflow: visible; font-size: 0px; line-height: 0px; text-align: left; display: inline; width: 1px; height: 1px;"
        dir="ltr" id="ebDiv03330255262235271">
        <div
            style="border: 0px none; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; top: 0px; left: 0px; overflow: visible; font-size: 0px; line-height: 0px; text-align: left; display: inline;"
            dir="ltr" id="ebBannerDiv_30573327_03330255262235271">
            <div id="ebIframeDiv_30573327_03330255262235271">

<!-- ----- This iframe  ---------- -->

              <iframe marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px" scrolling="no"
                    id="ebBannerIFrame_30573327_03330255262235271"
                    src="http://ds.serving-sys.com/BurstingRes/Site-6171/WSFolders/4070092//index.html?v=_2_43_1_0"
                    allowtransparency="true"
                    onload="(function(e) { var event = new EBG.Events.Event(EBG.Events.EventNames.ELEMENT_LOADED);event.dispatcher = this;event.eventData = { DOMEvent: e, elementId: &quot;ebBannerIFrame_30573327_03330255262235271&quot;, adUId:&quot;30573327_03330255262235271&quot; };event.timing = EBG.Events.EventTiming.ONTIME_AND_AFTER;EBG.eventMgr.dispatchEvent(event);} )(typeof arguments != &quot;undefined&quot; ? arguments[0] : null);"
                    style="border: 0px none; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 1350px; height: 920px; z-index: 0; clip: rect(auto, auto, auto, auto); position: absolute;"
                    frameborder="0"></iframe>
            </div>
            <img id="ebBlankImg_30573327_03330255262235271"
                src="http://ds.serving-sys.com/BurstingCachedScripts/Res/blank_1X1.gif"
                style="border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;" height="1" width="1">
        </div>
    </div>
    <iframe src="javascript:&quot;<html>

        <body style='background: transparent'></body>
        </html>
        &quot;" style="width: 1px; height: 11px; visibility: visible;"
        marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="no"
        name="google_ads_iframe_/6411/onl.adtester_1"
        id="google_ads_iframe_/6411/onl.adtester_1" frameborder="0"
        height="11" width="1">
    </iframe>
</div>
```

You may use firefox, right click, inspect elements to sse whats happening

Comment: probably load that iframe before the content is loaded. Actually I don't know as the ads are added dynamically. You may push it in to the background by modifying the z-index to -1, but as you don't know ids or classes, it's difficult